# HazelcastSerializationException using Subzero/Kryo as global serializer when calling CacheManager.createCache()

Tags: java, hazelcast, kryo

I am trying to set up Hazelcast in a client-server configuration, for use with the JCache API in the client. It's a multi-tenant setup, so I have to create individual caches dynamically in the client code, not in the Hazelcast configuration. Some of the cached objects are from a third-party library and not Serializable, so I'm using [Subzero](https://github.com/jerrinot/subzero) to pull in [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) as the global serializer.

When I set up Kryo to override the Java native serialization, I get the following error right away on CacheManager.createCache(name, String.class, Object.class):

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: There is no suitable de-serializer for type 6000. This exception is likely to be caused by differences in the serialization configuration between members or between clients and members.
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.newHazelcastSerializationException(AbstractSerializationService.java:238)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:265)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:574)
at com.hazelcast.config.CacheConfig.readFactories(CacheConfig.java:644)
at com.hazelcast.config.CacheConfig.readData(CacheConfig.java:557)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:158)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:105)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:50)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:187)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.NodeEngineImpl.toObject(NodeEngineImpl.java:322)
at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.cache.CacheCreateConfigMessageTask.extractCacheConfigFromMessage(CacheCreateConfigMessageTask.java:87)
at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.cache.CacheCreateConfigMessageTask.processMessage(CacheCreateConfigMessageTask.java:56)
at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.initializeAndProcessMessage(AbstractMessageTask.java:123)
at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.doRun(AbstractMessageTask.java:111)
at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.run(AbstractMessageTask.java:101)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:155)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:125)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:100)
at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:96)
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:33)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:154)
at com.hazelcast.client.cache.impl.ClientCacheHelper.createCacheConfig(ClientCacheHelper.java:126)
at com.hazelcast.client.cache.impl.HazelcastClientCacheManager.createCacheConfig(HazelcastClientCacheManager.java:137)
at com.hazelcast.cache.impl.AbstractHazelcastCacheManager.createCacheInternal(AbstractHazelcastCacheManager.java:122)
at com.hazelcast.cache.impl.AbstractHazelcastCacheManager.createCache(AbstractHazelcastCacheManager.java:150)
at com.hazelcast.cache.impl.AbstractHazelcastCacheManager.createCache(AbstractHazelcastCacheManager.java:67)
at com.veeva.App.testCache(App.java:57)
at com.veeva.App.main(App.java:90)
```

This appears to be coming when the client is sending the cache configuration information to the server.

For my investigation, I'm running demo servers on my local machine from the Hazelcast 3.10.2 download. (I started working with Hazelcast 3.9.3. Got the same outcome. Upgraded hoping it would change. Even went back to 3.8.9. Same.) I modified the console.sh script to include Subzero and the JCache API on the classpath, and reference my own config file:

```
java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhazelcast.config=../lib/hazelcast-jcache.xml -cp ../lib/hazelcast-all-3.10.2.jar:../lib/cache-api-1.1.0.jar:../lib/subzero-all-0.7.jar com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp
```

My hazelcast-jcache.xml configuration file is based on hazelcast-default.xml with the following differences:

```
<cache name="default">
    <key-type class-name="java.lang.Object"/>
    <value-type class-name="java.lang.Object"/>
    <statistics-enabled>true</statistics-enabled>
    <management-enabled>true</management-enabled>
    <backup-count>1</backup-count>
    <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
    <eviction size="1000" max-size-policy="ENTRY_COUNT" eviction-policy="LFU"/>
</cache>    
<serialization>
    <serializers>
        <global-serializer override-java-serialization="true">
            info.jerrinot.subzero.Serializer
        </global-serializer>
    </serializers>
</serialization>
```

My client code is configured with all the same library dependencies as the server:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.jerrinot</groupId>
        <artifactId>subzero-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.7</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
                <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-all</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am excluding the transitive hazelcast dependency in Subzero, so I can specify my own version.

My client is configured programmatically to be the same as the servers:

```
private void init() throws URISyntaxException {
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    config.setInstanceName("Boogabooga");
    SubZero.useAsGlobalSerializer(config); // internally calls setOverrideJavaSerialization(true)
    instance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);
    CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider("com.hazelcast.cache.HazelcastCachingProvider");
    cacheManager = cachingProvider.getCacheManager(new URI(instance.getName()), null);
}
```

The code that creates the cache is simply

```
private void testCache(String cacheName, String key, Object value) {
    Cache<String, Object> myCache = cacheManager.getCache(cacheName);
    if (myCache == null) {
        LOG.info("Creating Cache " + cacheName);
        CompleteConfiguration<String, Object> cacheConfig = new MutableConfiguration<String, Object>()
                .setTypes(String.class, Object.class);
        myCache = cacheManager.createCache(cacheName, cacheConfig);
    } else {
        LOG.info("Found Cache " + cacheName);
    }
    myCache.put(key, object);

    Object objectReturned = myCache.get(key);
    LOG.info("returned == put ?: " + Objects.equals(object, objectReturned));
}
```

I've tried changing the declared key type from String to just Object, so the cache is Object-Object. No difference.

If I disable the overriding of Java serialization by Kryo in both the client and server, everything *almost* works. The createCache() call works fine, with String, Object, and/or Serializable as class arguments. I can store simple serializable and non-serializable objects in the server caches. The classes don't have to be in the server classpath.

Where I run into trouble again is when I try to cache an *array* of non-serializable objects. The array serialization apparently gets kicked to the Java serializer, which then freaks out when the individual elements are non-serializable. So I'm back to trying to get the Kryo overriding working.

One workaround I've found is to wrap any array or Collection with a non-serializable class so Kryo gets called at the top level instead of native serializer. I can create a utility that wraps Cache and implements the workaround with a generic wrapper class, but that's a hack and I would much prefer that Kryo just handle all my serialization. It's supposed to be faster and more efficient anyway.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm having the same problem. Using SubZero 0.9 and Hazelcast 3.12. After switching to JCache, I'm getting HazelcastSerializationException (There is no suitable de-serializer for type 6000. This exception is likely to be caused by differences in the serialization configuration between members or between clients and members)

Comment: @SinaNourian, what we finally got working was the workaround mentioned in the last paragraph. We disabled the override, so Serializable stuff goes through Java serialization. We wrap any collections or arrays of non-serializable objects with a non-serializable wrapper class, so the entire thing gets kicked over to Kryo. After doing that, we also switched all configuration to the client side, because there are problems if there are any conflicts between what the server XML is and the client config, including the signature of the key and value classes. So try doing the config in just 1 place.